# Javascript - count all lines of code of html document

Tags: javascript

How to count all lines of code at website? I'm trying something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

but it doesn't display ALL lines of current page (skipping scripts or something?). Is there better way to count it?

Comment: Are you trying the count the lines of the source code? The lines of displayed text? The amount of DOM elements?

Comment: I need to count all lines of website DOM

Comment: I'm creating simple chrome extension and I need to count all elements of currently visited page. So for example on stackoverflow, I need to count lines of code of current page :) Just a practice

Comment: @michal: *"... I need to count all elements of currently visited page..."* and *"...I need to count lines of code of current page..."* Those are very different things.

Answer (score 1):

Counting the lines of the `innerHTML` of the root element in the current document would be as follows:

```
var x = document.documentElement.innerHTML.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length;
```

```js
var x = document.documentElement.innerHTML.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length

console.log(x);
```

```html
<h1>This is a Header</h1>
<h2>This is a Medium Header</h2>
<p>Send me mail at <a href="mailto:me@domain.com">
support@yourcompany.com</a>.</p>
<p> This is a new paragraph!</p>
```

Note that it won't account for the root (`<html>`) tags or anything that is outside of them, I.E. your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration.

If you were looking to just get the lines of that within the `<body>` tag, you could modify it to do so:

```
var x = document.body.innerHTML.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length;
```

[Noted By T.J. Crowder:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846734/javascript-count-all-lines-of-code-of-html-document/46846939?noredirect=1#comment80641998_46846939)

> Beware that this counts the number of lines in the browser's rendition of the HTML for the parsed DOM structure, not the original HTML, and the two can be different. For instance, most browsers will replace newlines within (e.g., `<span newlinehere attr="val">` with a space.

Comment: Thanks it still miss some lines, but I think it's acceptable and won't make it better :)

Comment: @michal No problem.

Comment: @michal & George: Beware that this counts the number of lines in the *browser's* rendition of the HTML for the parsed DOM structure, not the original HTML, and the two can be different. For instance, most browsers will replace newlines within (e.g., `<span newlinehere attr="val">` with a space.

Comment: FWIW, you could include the `<html>` and `</html>` tags by using `outerHTML` on `documentElement`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's a good point, I'll be sure to include the information. (I was under the impression that `.outerHTML` isn't as well supported, which is why I didn't include it. Please correct me if I'm wrong :) )

Comment: @George: `outerHTML` support is universal these days, and it's a [specified feature](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Parsing/#widl-Element-outerHTML) (that spec is listed as a dependency by [the HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#dependencies), calling out `outerHTML`).